# Получить значение id из ссылки

Tags: php, get

Давайте перейдем сразу к сути) У меня есть директория console/index.php. Когда перехожу по ссылке мойсайт.ру/console то открывается данные индекс. Также в этой ссылке ( не важно каким образом, долго описывать ) есть id, т.е. получается допустим ссылка мойсайт.ру/console?id=7. Так вот, получить этот id в классе index.php который находится в папке console используя метод $_GET['id]. Но вот теперь сам вопрос. Допустим, мне надо получить этот id в папке console/rcon/index.php, используя $_GET['id] ничего не выводит. Но в тоже время, если я перейду по ссылке мойсайт.ру/console/rcon/index.php?id=7 то выводит. Искал на русских/английских форумах, но к сожалению ничего не нашел(.

Comment: если вы сначала попадаете на первый файл, а потом как-то переходите ко второму, то либо пробрасывайте этот ид дальше по ссылкам, либо сохраните в сессию, и берите оттуда.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за то, что вы ответили и решили мне помочь. На ссылку мойсайт.ру/console/rcon/index.php никто не переходит (так и должно быть), поэтому даже и не знаю, как пробрасывать дальше айди. А вот по-поводу сохранения в ссесию очень даже интересная мысль, но возможно есть еще какие-то идеи. Спасибо еще раз за помощь.

Comment: А какая ваша конечная цель? Можно пример?

Answer (score 2):

Глеб, походу Вы не понимаете принцип работы глобальной переменной `$_GET`.

> Ассоциативный массив переменных, переданных скрипту через параметры URL (известные также как строка запроса).
>   [Тут написано](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php)

То есть, если Вы ничего не передаете через адресную строку, то ничего и получите.

Comment: Я передаю в адресную строку значение id. В папке rcon в index.php я не могу получить значение. П.C.: $_GET['id] ничего не выводит.